# How to deal with 'Wrong StackExchange' questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

On SO I frequently see questions like:

- Should I use skinny Controllers and Fat Models
- Should I use DTO's for Models
- How should I structure my projects (Data-Layer vs Logic Layer vs Presentation Layer)
- What are Pro's and Cons of Memebership Providers? Should I build my own?

I'm always torn about what to do with these posts. Many of them are legitimate questions but won't get the proper attention in SO. Sometimes they get a little blurb, other times they get (understandably) down-voted. Often they are just ignored.

It's not just that these posts don't belong on SO. These Posts seem well suited to Programmers.SE.

Are moderators able to move posts to different StackExchange sites?

Should Moderators and Power Users be empowered to do so?

Comment: If you're not an active member of a migration target, please don't suggest it (i.e., if you aren't active on Programmers, don't flag and say "Hey, move this to programmers!")  We have enough eyes on this kind of stuff.

Comment: this is why people resent stack. I ask a question aimed at "how can I be of help?" and I get back an F-Off and downvote. It's also why i stay off meta completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be sure that the question isn't grounded in any kind of objective problem that could receive concise, verifiable answers. The issue with these types of questions is that they can go on forever due to the scope being poorly defined. Sometimes new users give us great questions that are just asked less than ideally. If it's clear that the question could be edited to be of a much narrower scope, consider doing so.

If not, overly broad questions should be closed quickly because ironically they tend to receive quite a few answers, creating a sort of perennial distraction on the front page of the site. There's several closing criteria to choose from, but they all basically point to the question being fundamentally off topic for the site.

You can choose to recommend that the question be migrated to a site within our migration path, but please do not vote to do so unless you feel that the question is excellent, just asked in the wrong place. It's not required, but editing to fix any grammatical / spelling / formatting issues in a question prior to migrating it is always appreciated. We're the flagship site of the network and we're *notorious* for migrating ... not so great questions, which is something that we really should be mindful of. In other words, don't just shift junk from our yard to another. Don't migrate crap.

If the site you have in mind is not in our migration path, you can flag the question as 'other' and let us know where you think it should go. If you do this, *please* tell us why you think the question is fantastic, at least to the point that you can in the flag dialog. We (moderators) don't usually migrate a question outside of the available paths without a compelling reason, especially to beta sites.

Comment: Interesting you say this. I see many posts that are very completely open-ended but worthwhile conversation points. Some very worthwhile. I'm not a member of Programmers but I've read some Posts and feel that kind of content would be more appropriate there. I always mention to the OP that their idea would be more welcome in another forum, but I didn't know I could flag it. I will in future. I hope **Programmers** is an available option because the type I have in mind ALWAYS fit in well there.

Comment: @DaveA It used to be, but .. people kept sending them stuff that was more or less 'as a programmer, how do you do (xyz)' or 'what IDE do you like?' or book lists / recommendations, basically everything on the [bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) side of the fence. We do occasionally send over a question that's well grounded in theoretical software engineering, fitting the 'good subjective' criteria in the link that I sent. But, I doubt that PSE will ever be placed in our migration path again.

Answer (score 2):

Flag as off-topic; you'll get a (small) choice of where it would be better off–what you do now?

If a good place isn't shown I'll either leave as off-topic, or custom-flag and suggest a forum.

Comment: never even knew this feature existed. do you have to have serious rank to do it, or can anyone do it?

Comment: @DaveA Flagging is at 15 rep; not sure about migrating.

Comment: 15 great. I wish the migrate vote was more readily available. I would use it 10 times a day and I'm only on the asp.net MVC forums.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Migrating comes with close votes.

Answer (score 2):

You can flag questions as off-topic, at which point you can choose from a list of five sites it could go on instead. Once you get 3K rep, you can vote to migrate instead of flagging. However, only diamond mods can migrate to any site not in that list.

Comment: Significantly, Programmers is not an option, because too many people were voting to move junk questions there and they got sick of it.